# How to read the HTML file in Second activity in android?

Tags: android

Hi I am writing the application to open HTML file.so for initial activity I am mentioning in AndroidManifest file as

```
 <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
```

In the activity I am getting the URI  of HTML file by using following code.

```
 Uri mDataUri = = getIntent().getData();
```

and then by using following code I am reading the data of HTML file by using the following code

```
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        InputStream input = cr.openInputStream(mDataUri);
```

from InputStream I am parsing the data and getting the content.

But now client want the Splash screen in the middle ,so if I read the data in SplashScrren I am unable to send to the SecondScreen because that file Content is more(after converting to string length is:3,00,000).

Now Same HTML How can I  read in Second Screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we are putting the MimeTypes as text/html for an activity,you can read the data in That activity only,you cannot read from Another activity,so you can store locally and access in Second Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare the file in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. If you place your HTML file in the `asset` folder of your project you will able to use the [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) provided from the `Application` class in any activity:

`AssetManager assetMgr = getApplication().getAssets();`

You are able to get the same value for `input` by getting the `InputStream`:

`InputStream input = assetMgr.open("nameOfFile.html");`

If you are putting the content in a WebView you can just load file by name:

`WebView webView = new Webview(context);`

`webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/nameOfFile.html");`

Comment: the attachment file is not static.attachment i have to  read from Email .

Comment: On second thought, I think this is still the best way to go, you just need to write out the HTML file out to the device (assets folder or otherwise). The string is too big to fit into an `Intent` and takes up a huge chunk of space so long as it exists in RAM. I just found this link that seems to agree with some kind of solution like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496700/maximum-length-of-intent-putextra-method-force-close

Comment: BTW, I have been assuming you are unable to pass along that same URI to the next activity in an `Intent`, is that an option for you? Does only your first activity have access to the raw file for some reason?

Comment: yes..for first activity i am mentioning  <data android:mimeType="text/html" /> so i can get the data by using Uri mDataUri = = getIntent().getData();..but this will not available for secondactivity