# Android startActivity doesn't work for some images but not others

Tags: android, android-activity

Sorry about the confusing question title, wasn't sure how better to phrase it...

The problem is that I have a bunch of downloaded image thumbnails on the screen. If any one of them is clicked, a new activity should be launched that features (amongst other things) a larger version of the image.

It works fine for some of the images, but I realised by happenstance that for more than half of the images it just does nothing. The code is executed (I get log messages) but nothing happens.

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageBitmap(locationBitmap.bitmap);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View image) {
        Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "You selected location: " + locationBitmap.location);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AnswerActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("question_text", question_text);
        i.putExtra("question_title", question_title);
        i.putExtra("location", locationBitmap.location);
        i.putExtra("bitmap", locationBitmap.bitmap);
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "About to start the activity...");
        context.startActivity(i);
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Started the activity...");
    }
});
```

All of the log messages are produced correctly, but sometimes the activity doesn't change and sometimes it does. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure but use yourclassname.this instead of context.

Comment: check locationBitmap.bitmap is null or not.put one condition if null then set default image else set imageView.setImageBitmap(locationBitmap.bitmap);

Comment: try this logic and see what happen.

Comment: @Harshid - thanks for your suggestion, I'll look for null's. However, all of the image's do render successfully on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The answer seems to be that the bundle has a size limitation - some of the file's are exceeding it and some aren't.

Passing through the name of a file, rather than the bitmap itself, works.

Related question: [Maximum length of Intent putExtra method? (Force close)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496700/maximum-length-of-intent-putextra-method-force-close)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with getting image **null**.

check `locationBitmap.bitmap` is **null** or **not** put one condition if null then set default image else set `imageView.setImageBitmap(locationBitmap.bitmap);`

This type issue generate many user.