# Is there anyway to pass Image data through an intent?

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I know how to do this converting it to a bitmap, but I want an Image (android.media) on the receiver side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you actually doing? google something called "URI" or check it [directly](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you  want to pass only one bitmap at a time, I suggest creating a static variable in a class. and assign the bitmap object to it, and use it in the receiver class.

But if this is very big bitmap, it may cause OutOfMemory issue.

Comment: I'll try to do this, then I'll give you some feedback

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do this. Even if you create a `Serializable` or `Parcelable` object that includes your data like this:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing-object-by-intent-serializableparcelable.html

which you may be able to do, by creatively encoding your image.

But an `Intent` has a limitation in size. See this post here:

[Maximum length of Intent putExtra method? (Force close)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496700/maximum-length-of-intent-putextra-method-force-close)

It says 1MB, but in my experience it might be as high as 4MB, depending on the platform (I may have that wrong, I don't have a specific reference to Android documentation to support it, but I see errors that appear to support it).

I'm sure you can move a lot of images within this restriction, but for any that fall outside of it, you will need a "work around" - which you should then probably make the "standard" and avoid the issue altogether.