# How to send image from one activity to another activity?

Tags: android

How to take pic from camera and send image to second activity and in second activity image will be shown on image view.kindly give me the code.
i will be very thankful.

Comment: Have a look at the `putExtra()` method of the class `Intent`

Comment: Welcome to SO! To be sure to get good and useful answers to your questions, you must ensure that you are providing enough information in your post that describe your problem - even better with a code example of yours!

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the informantion on the `Intent` as an `Extra`.

An example:

```
startActivity(new Intent(PresentActivity.this, NextActivity.class).putExtra("Key", "Value"));
```

More specifically for taking a picture and showing it on an ImageView, use an `startActivityForResult`.
Example code:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), REQUEST_CODE);
```

This will call a new activity which will take a picture, then you'll only need to call the `onActivityResult` method on the same activity you called the previous code and handle the result (take the picture uri and set it on the `ImageView`).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29) and the [getExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29) method.
Here are some code snippets:

```
//First Acitivity
Bitmap img=//set here the image you got from the camera.


Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable("image", img);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);

//Second Activity
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("image");
```

If you didn't already think about, how to start the camera and get the image, I'd suggest you to use `startActivityForResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap capturedImage = // set your image here
File tempDir = this.getCacheDir();
File tempFile = null;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".png", tempDir);
    fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);

    if (capturedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fos)) {
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
        result.putExtra("fileUri", fileUri);
        this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
        this.finish();
    } else {

    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

you can't put image to intent. intent extra has size limit of 1MB.

just save your image to temp file and send it's uri.

Comment: I thought the limitation of 1MB would have been fixed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496700/maximum-length-of-intent-putextra-method-force-close , like it´s written here? But creating a temp file should work, no matter wether extra has a limit or not

Comment: @SebastianWalla  I can confirm that the 1MB limit is not fixed.  I doubt it really won't be fixed either.