# Activity receives Null from Parcelable object

Tags: android, android-intent, null, parcelable, serializable

I am using a parcelable object to pass through an intent. My object looks like this

`enter code here`public class Recipe  implements Parcelable{
    private  List recipe = null;
    private  List ingredients = null;
    private  String preparation;

```
public Recipe(List<String> recipe, List<String> ingredients,
        String preparation) {
    this.recipe = recipe;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.preparation = preparation;
}

public Recipe(Parcel source) {

    source.readStringList(recipe);
    source.readStringList(ingredients);
    this.preparation = source.readString();
}

public List<String> getRecipe() {
    return recipe;
}

public List<String> getIngredients() {
    return ingredients;
}

public String getPreparation() {
    return preparation;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStringList(recipe);
    dest.writeStringList(ingredients);
    dest.writeString(preparation);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Recipe> CREATOR = new Creator<Recipe>() {

    @Override
    public Recipe[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Recipe[size];
    }

    @Override
    public Recipe createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Recipe(source);
    }
};}
```

I put the data in to Intent like this

```
enter code here @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);

    dbMan = new XmlManager();
    try {
        db = dbMan.parse();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        System.err.println("XmlPullParserException " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IO Excepion " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new MyBaseExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader,
            listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            sendChildList = listDataChild 
                    .get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosition).toString();
            sendRecipe = dbMan.getRecipyByCriteria(db, sendChildList);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "sendet" + sendChildList, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ShowRecipe.class);
            in.putExtra("sendRecipe", sendRecipe);

            startActivity(in);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Well i debug this Part of code and i know the sendRecipe Object was instantiates and data is correct. so i put this thing in intent and send it to next Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_recipe);
    findeRecipe = (Recipe)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("sendRecipe");
```

At this place the Intent receives NULL. It's funny thing because when I send a String or int its receive correctly. I sit here scened day an debug this thing read questions about Parcelable do everything right i thing and nothing works correctly.

Comment: Maybe you facing size limit?
Look at the: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496700/maximum-length-of-intent-putextra-method-force-close

Comment: its can´t be what i send are 2 list with 4 or 5 Strings and a single String

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is that you use application context: `Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext()...` Try to pass activity instead.

Comment: What do you mean to try to pass a activity instead. To initialized a intent you have to give it a parameter getApplicationContext() or getBaseContext().

Comment: I mean MainActivity.this, for example