# sending data using intent extras crashes app without any error messages

Tags: android, android-intent

App crashes with no error messages when i try to send date to my main activity class.

I have a launchActivity thats run a Async process to load data. I then parse the json into classes and send them to the my MainActivity. However when i try to send the two objects that have data, the app crashes. but if i comment either one of them, it works.

```
intent.putExtra("class1", class1);
intent.putExtra("class2", class2);
```

both of my classes implement serializable. I was wondering is there a size limit to the intent ?

There is no system dialogu not any error message when the crash happens.

Logcat message - http://pastebin.com/Lz8W5KXK

Comment: Please post the logcat output. There should be a stack trace from the crash there.

Comment: There isn't any kind of error message in the log which is why i'm confused

Comment: What are the symptoms of the crash? Do you get a system dialog saying that the app has stopped? If so, it's hard to believe that there's nothing in logcat; the system will always log uncaught exceptions.

Comment: There's no system dialog either. checkout this link - http://pastebin.com/Lz8W5KXK

Answer (score 0):

For send objects, your object classes must `implement serializable`.

Example:

```
public class Class1 implements Serializable {...}
```

Then, you are able to do:

```
intent.putExtra("class1", class1);
```

Comment: But,  if any of your classes have an attribute that is not serializable, like bitmap,  the app will crash. Check this.

Comment: both my classes have attributes that are either string or int

Comment: So,  I think,  the problem must be the size of the object.  Like described here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496700/maximum-length-of-intent-putextra-method-force-close The limit is less than 1Mb.