# for Android is it a good idea to pass a list of object from one Activity to another ?

Tags: android

Is it a good idea to pass a list of object from one Activity to another for Android ?

It is quiet troublesome to pass a list of object in an intent, and I wonder whether it affect the performance if the object list is too large or the object is too complicated.

Is it a better solution to get the list of object from other place, for example, query the DB once more , or save the list of object in a temporary class and fetch it in new Activity?

Comment: Intents are used to send primitive datatypes to other Activity. Its better to fetch list of objects in Other Activity rather them passing.

Comment: Have your objects implement parcelable, then you can pass them through bundle/extra OR best idea is to use a database

Comment: Cache, using for example Gson; Read from DataBase (SQLite); Use public static List in Activity A

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are passing `Parcelable` objects' list, nothing's wrong when passing through `Intent`. Regarding performance, that is up to you and the amount of data you pass.

As per my experience, If you are passing data up to **1MB** of size, it should be fine. Anything above that will fail as this seems to be the limit. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496700/maximum-length-of-intent-putextra-method-force-close).

Besides, you are welcome to use preferences, SQLite, files or static-object-referencing methodologies to fetch your data anytime and anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Solution1 : Use Intent

Send :

```
     Intent data = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
    data.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Constant.LIST_OBJECT, 
              (ArrayList<?    extends Parcelable>) getObjects());
```

receive :

```
      List<YOUR_OBJECT> objects = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constant.LIST_OBJECT);
```

Solution2 :

```
public class SessionData {

  private static SessionData instance;
  private final List< YOUR_OBJECT > listSessionObjects; 

  private SessionData() {
     listSessionObjects = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public static final SessionData getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
          instance = new SessionData();
    }
    return instance;
  }

   public List<YOUR_OBJECT> getListSessionObjects() {
      return listSessionObjects;
  }

  public void setListSessionObjects(List<YOUR_OBJECT > objects) {
     listSessionObjects = objects
  }

 }
```

to use it :

```
 SessionData.getInstance().getListSessionObjects();
 SessionData.getInstance(). setListSessionObjects(objects);
```