# How to pass networkImageView to another fragment? bitmap or URI

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, android-imageview, android-viewholder

long story short, ive got fragmnet (catalog) which holds cardview, that fills from json file that stream from my server.

on card click, im poping DialogFragment, that asks the user to fill how many items he want from this specific "product", after i get the quantity, my dilemma starts...

How to pass the image itself to the dialog and from the dialog to the fragment (userCart),
 I want to display the image again in listview in  userCartFragment.

I know passing view isn't a solution, but i read that maybe with uri its is possible, and so with the bitmap convertion to array.

Which way you guys think would be better, or maybe you have any better solution for this.

Any advise/snippet  would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better Solution: **Load image with URI**

The reason:Simple&Uncomplicated,

If you use Glide, you just code like this 
`Glide.with(this).load("YOUR URL").into(imageView);` 
It's just one step. Make's your URL to be **public static** so variable can access in all class.

If you use bitmap conversion at least you need 3-4 step so you can load image to another fragment.

Comment: it's same, i just give you example. if you use picasso,you just pass your URI to your picasso code.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Uri** to pass images.

Otherwise, if the image size is too large it might create some memory issues. Also, there is a size limit (1 MB) in passing extras between activities or fragments.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496700/maximum-length-of-intent-putextra-method-force-close)

Comment: @2Stoned Always welcome. If you want to manage image loading efficiently. Try any of the libraries from the link according to your requirements. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide