# Android intent vs aidl

Tags: android, android-intent, computer-science, aidl

I am going through the process of learning Android basics. please forgive me for the noob question.

one thing i fail to understand(even after reading so much documentaion) is why do we need aidl for IPC when even simple intents do the job. 
*(as i understand implicit/explicit intents creates the new component in the same/new process.)*

at the end of the day its just data transfer and calling some function directly or indirectly. what is the key difference and use cases?

Comment: The main difference, i think, is that Intent input data size is [limited](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12497065/3858030). You can use [Messenger](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html?hl=en) pattern, it uses aidl, but it is much more simplier to use.

Comment: thanks @Ufkoku, i am just trying to fix my mental model of the whole picture.

Comment: intents are used in "started" services and are relatively slow, `AIDL` is used in "bound" ones and direct `Binder` transactions are much faster and the param passing is a lot easier, more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)