# Firebase RecyclerView Onclick with more data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've been trying to get Onclik events on RecyclerView to display the same data that the RecyclerView had in a new activity with even more data that wasn't previously there. Right now I have data like name, phone number but I would like to add morelike website... So far the code I tried is crashing when i click on the View. I don't know what is wrong. can anyone help ?

Here's my main fragment

```
public class Entreprisesfrag extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseReference dbref;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

public Entreprisesfrag() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entreprises, container, 
false);

    recyclerView= view.findViewById(R.id.recv);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    linearLayout= view.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_list_layout);

    firebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    dbref= firebaseDatabase.getReference("Entreprises");
return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class,ViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter= 
new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class, ViewHolder>
            (entreprises_class.class,R.layout.entreprises_list, 
ViewHolder.class,dbref.orderByChild("nom")) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, 
entreprises_class model, int position) {
            viewHolder.details(getActivity(), model.getNom(),model.getNum(), 
model.getSecteur(), model.getSpécialité(), model.getVille(), 
model.getImage());

        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) 
{

            ViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, 
viewType);

            viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new ViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                    TextView textView= 
view.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_nom);
                    TextView textView1= 
view.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_secteur);
                    TextView textView2= 
view.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_sous_secteur);
                    TextView textView3= 
view.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_ville);
                    TextView textView4= 
view.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_num);


                    ImageView 
imageView=view.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_image);

                    String snom= textView.getText().toString();
                    String ssec= textView1.getText().toString();
                    String ssp= textView2.getText().toString();
                    String sv= textView3.getText().toString();
                    String snum= textView4.getText().toString();


                    Drawable drawable= imageView.getDrawable();

                    Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

                    Intent i= new Intent(view.getContext(), 
entProfileFull.class);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream= new 
ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, 
byteArrayOutputStream);

                    byte[] bytes= byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                    i.putExtra("image", bytes);
                    i.putExtra("nom", snom);
                    i.putExtra("secteur", ssec);
                    i.putExtra("spécialité", ssp);
                    i.putExtra("ville", sv);
                    i.putExtra("num", snum);
                    startActivity(i);






                }

                @Override
                public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

                }
            });
            return viewHolder;
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

public void recherche(String texte){
    Query mQuery= dbref.orderByChild("spécialité");




FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class,ViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter= 
new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class, ViewHolder>
            (entreprises_class.class,R.layout.entreprises_list, 
ViewHolder.class,mQuery) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, 
entreprises_class model, int position) {
            viewHolder.details(getActivity(), model.getNom(),model.getNum(), 
model.getSecteur(), model.getSpécialité(), model.getVille(), 
model.getImage());

        }


        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) 
{

            ViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, 
viewType);

            viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new ViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                    TextView textView= 
view.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_nom);
                    TextView textView1= 
view.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_secteur);
                    TextView textView2= 
view.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_sous_secteur);
                    TextView textView3= 
view.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_ville);
                    TextView textView4= 
view.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_num);


                    ImageView 
imageView=view.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_image);

                    String snom= textView.getText().toString();
                    String ssec= textView1.getText().toString();
                    String ssp= textView2.getText().toString();
                    String sv= textView3.getText().toString();
                    String snum= textView4.getText().toString();


                    Drawable drawable= imageView.getDrawable();

                    Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

                    Intent i= new Intent(view.getContext(), 
entProfileFull.class);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream= new 
ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, 
byteArrayOutputStream);

                    byte[] bytes= byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                    i.putExtra("image", bytes);
                    i.putExtra("nom", snom);
                    i.putExtra("secteur", ssec);
                    i.putExtra("spécialité", ssp);
                    i.putExtra("ville", sv);
                    i.putExtra("num", snum);
                    startActivity(i);






                }

                @Override
                public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

                }
            });
            return viewHolder;
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}



@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.recherche_activity_menu_item, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Nom, Spécialité ou Ville");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            recherche(query);

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            recherche(newText);


            return false;
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.recherche)
    {

    }
    else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.filtrer)
    { 
        FiltreDialog();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void FiltreDialog() {
    String [] Options={"Spécialité", "Ville"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Afficher par:")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_sort_black_24dp)
            .setItems(Options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(which==0){

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class,ViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter= 
new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class, ViewHolder>

(entreprises_class.class,R.layout.entreprises_list, 
ViewHolder.class,dbref.orderByChild("spécialité")) {
                            @Override
                            protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder 
viewHolder, entreprises_class model, int position) {
                                viewHolder.details(getActivity(), 
model.getNom(),model.getNum(), model.getSecteur(), model.getSpécialité(), 
model.getVille(), model.getImage());

                            }
                        };
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

                    }
                    else if(which==1){

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class,ViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter= 
new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class, ViewHolder>

(entreprises_class.class,R.layout.entreprises_list, 
ViewHolder.class,dbref.orderByChild("ville")) {
                            @Override
                            protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder 
viewHolder, entreprises_class model, int position) {
                                viewHolder.details(getActivity(), 
model.getNom(),model.getNum(), model.getSecteur(), model.getSpécialité(), 
model.getVille(), model.getImage());

                            }
                        };
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

                    }

                }
            });
    builder.show();
}

}
```

Over Here is my new Activity

```
public class entProfileFull extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar mtoolbar;
TextView textView, textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4;
ImageView imageView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ent_profile_full);

    mtoolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    textView=findViewById(R.id.nom_entreprise_full);
    textView1=findViewById(R.id.secteur_entreprise_full);
    textView2= findViewById(R.id.sp_entreprise_full);
    textView3=findViewById(R.id.entreprise_ville);
    textView4=findViewById(R.id.entreprise_num_full);



    imageView=findViewById(R.id.entreprise_image_full);


    byte[] bytes=getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
    String nom= getIntent().getStringExtra("nom");
    String secteur= getIntent().getStringExtra("secteur");
    String spécialité= getIntent().getStringExtra("spécialité");
    String ville= getIntent().getStringExtra("ville");
    String num= getIntent().getStringExtra("num");



    Bitmap bm= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    textView.setText(nom);
    textView1.setText(secteur);
    textView2.setText(spécialité);
    textView3.setText(ville);
    textView4.setText(num);


    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);



}




public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

And this is my ViewHolder Class

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

View mView;

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mView=itemView;

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            vclickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });

    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            vclickListener.onItemLongClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void details(Context cntx, String nom, String num, String secteur, 
String spécialité,String ville, String image){

    TextView textView= mView.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_nom);
    TextView textView1= mView.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_secteur);
    TextView textView2= mView.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_sous_secteur);
    TextView textView3= mView.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_ville);
    TextView textView4= mView.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_num);
    ImageView imageView= mView.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_image);

    textView.setText(nom);
    textView1.setText(secteur);
    textView2.setText(spécialité);
    textView3.setText(ville);
    textView4.setText(num);
    Picasso.get().load(image).into(imageView);


}
private ViewHolder.ClickListener vclickListener;

public interface ClickListener{
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);

}
public void setOnClickListener(ViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener){
    vclickListener = clickListener;

}

}
```

Comment: Provide the logcat error. Where is it crashing? which view?

Comment: I think you should use `viewholder.itemView.setonClickListener` instead of `viewholder.setOnClickListener`

Comment: and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496700/maximum-length-of-intent-putextra-method-force-close , maybe the image you are sending over intent is more than 1MB

Comment: This is what I am getting                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{appsbyjoel.go/appsbyjoel.go.entProfileFull}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling itemView.setOnClickListener() from ViewHolder constructor. Because ViewHolder constructor is called from the onCreateViewHolder method. Henc you'll not have the position. So keep the itemView.setOnClickListener() methods inside onBindView() method

This will fix the issue

Comment: I don't even have an OnbindView method anywhere. Do I  need to have one ?