# Method of passing object to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Let's say I have a `RecyclerView` filled with Car objects. A Car has a lot of variables like **ID**, size, colour, logo, etc. Every car is saved to the database.

Now, when I want to open the `DetailActivity` about the specific Car, should I pass the [whole object into the new activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents) OR just an **ID** and get data from database in `DetailActivity` again?

Which solution will be more relevant and faster?

Comment: that depends on your needs, you may try both approaches and see which one suits you better. This is the only way to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass one or two properties then its fine. If it is more than two then it is preferred if you use id and query it from DB.

Answer (score 1):

First you should make your object implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable).

Once you have your object implemented the `Parcelable`, you attach it to the `Intent` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("extra_object_1", your_parcelable_object);
```

When you are ready to pull the object, use `intent.getParcelableExtra()`:

```
Intent intent  = Context.getIntent();
MyParcelable obj = (MyParcelable) intent.getParcelableExtra("extra_object_1");
```

Comment: Yeah, I know it's one of the solutions, but I was asking which one is better. Anyway, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

If object size is small, you should pass the data through the intent using `Parcelable`. if data size is large then pass the id to you activity and then get the data from database.

Based on this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12497065/1654263) you can pass 1 MB of data in Intent.

So choose the approach based on the situation.