# I am not able to send Bytearray data from activity to fragment

Tags: android, arrays, android-fragments, android-activity, bundle

I wanna send bytearray data from activity to fragment,
This is my code 
sending data from Activity

```
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putByteArray("bytearray",byteArray);
                            CustImageSignatureUploadFragment fragobj = new 
                            CustImageSignatureUploadFragment();
                            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

getting data in Fragment in onCreateView() method

```
   if (getArguments() != null) {
        byteArray = getArguments().getByteArray("bytearray");
        if (byteArray != null) {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, 
           byteArray.length);
            binding.custImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }
```

but I am getting error

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[Thread-8,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:205)
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:118)
    at com.jmr.agency.banking.ui.base.BaseFragment$3.<init>(BaseFragment.java:816)
    at com.jmr.agency.banking.ui.base.BaseFragment.<init>(BaseFragment.java:815)
    at com.jmr.agency.banking.ui_fragment.cust_img_signature_upload.CustImageSignatureUploadFragment.<init>(CustImageSignatureUploadFragment.java:62)
    at com.jmr.agency.banking.ui.facerecognition.FRAddPersonPreviewActivity.onCameraFrame(FRAddPersonPreviewActivity.java:200)
```

I have tried this

```
                               this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                               bundle.putByteArray("bytearray",byteArray);
                                    CustImageSignatureUploadFragment 
                         fragobj = new CustImageSignatureUploadFragment();
                                    fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Problem is `Can't create handler inside thread Thread` instead of sending `ByteArray`. What is line number `CustImageSignatureUploadFragment.java:62` ? show more code from `CustImageSignatureUploadFragment` class

Comment: This is the Fragment name where  I  have to send data

Comment: bro,please notice this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496700/maximum-length-of-intent-putextra-method-force-close**.you are trying to pass the image bitmap which usually more than 1MB which is maximum size availble put into bundle of intent

Answer (score 0):

To get byteArray do like below

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putByteArray("image",byteArray);


  // your fragment code 
CustImageSignatureUploadFragment 
                         fragobj = new CustImageSignatureUploadFragment();
                                    fragobj.setArguments(b);

byte[] array = getArgument().getByteArrayExtra("bytearray");
```

**Second Option**

If you trying to pass Bitmap.
To set argument as bungle.

```
bundle.putParcelable("bytearray", bytearray);
```

Get bitmap from Bundle by following code

```
Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("bytearray");
```

Comment: This is not My concern, I am not able to send data first

Comment: Are you trying to pass bitmap to Activity? @PoojaPatwa

Comment: No, I am passing bytearray

Answer (score 0):

Passing data inside fragment is too easy if you create newInstance of your fragment and pass your array.

```
   private byte[] bytes;

   public static CustImageSignatureUploadFragment newInstance(byte[] bytes) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        CustImageSignatureUploadFragment fragment = new CustImageSignatureUploadFragment();
        fragment.bytes = bytes;
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Then in your activity use:

```
CustImageSignatureUploadFragment fragobj = 
                        CustImageSignatureUploadFragment.newInstance(byteArray);
```

Comment: Then problem isn't in Fragment side. Share the code where you are creating Fragment object and opening it.

Comment: CustImageSignatureUploadFragment fragobj =
                                                CustImageSignatureUploadFragment.byteArray(byteArray);

Comment: or this Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putByteArray("bytearray",byteArray);
                                CustImageSignatureUploadFragment fragobj = new CustImageSignatureUploadFragment();
                                fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[Thread-8,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()...This is the error

Comment: In which action / method you are calling this code CustImageSignatureUploadFragment fragobj = new CustImageSignatureUploadFragment();