# Intent seems not sent between activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bitmap

I have wrote an app with 2 activities. One activity took a picture and the second one use it with some filters.

Activity 1:

```
Intent FilterSelectionIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PulsFiltersActivity.class);
FilterSelectionIntent.putExtra("PicTaken", currentBitmap);
startActivity(FilterSelectionIntent);
```

Acitivity 2:

```
    Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();
    mBitmap = bd.getParcelable("PicTaken");
```

I have put some breakpoints in the Activity 2 and it never stop at. As soon as I comment the "putExtra" in comment, I can reach the breakpoints. In my case, the activity is not started, I think the intent is wrong.

I know that one solution is to use Bitmap.compress and forward the result in the Output stream. but in my case, it take too much time. My android device is a very basic one and it takes 2s to save the bmp. this why I try to use the intent to pass argument but it seems not working.

I'm also open to save the bmp as tmp file but I can lose 2 sec.

Any idea .

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android

Comment: Intent intent = getIntent();                                                                      Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("PicTaken");

Comment: best way is to pass as byteArray

Comment: @sanatshukla your link is perfect

Comment: Check answer below. It is also possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitmap implements Parcelable, so you could always pass it in the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImg", bitmap);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImg");
```

Check it here : [How can I pass a Bitmap object from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have confused a couple of concepts of sending objects. In your `Activity 1`, you put the extra directly to the intent. In `Activity 2`, you try to get it back from a `Bundle`, which you did not put the `Bitmap` to. So try this in your activity 2:

```
mBitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("PicTaken");
```

Edit: I found some reports of Bitmaps being too big to send and activites not starting when sending Bitmaps. [Converting them to ByteArray may help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android)

Answer (score 0):

You also can store the bitmap into internal storage like this:

```
    final static String IMG_PATH= "bmp2Store"
    FileOutputStream streamOut;
    Bitmap image = currentBitmap;
    try {
            // Store bitmap into internal storage
            streamOut = mContext.openFileOutput(IMG_PATH, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, streamOut);
            streamOut.close();

            // Call ActivityB
            Intent intent= new Intent(this, ConsumirOfertaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

And in the activityB:

```
    final static String IMG_PATH= "bmp2Store"
    Bitmap bitmap;
    FileInputStream streamIn;

    try {
        streamIn = openFileInput(IMG_PATH);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(streamIn);
        streamIn.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass bitmap inside bundle:

Size of the **data you are allowed to pass through Bundle or Intent is very less (~1MB)**. Considering a object like Bitmap, there are high chances that memory allocated to it greater than 1MB. This can happen for any kind of object including byte array, String etc.

**Solution:**
Store your bitmap into File,  FileProvider, Singleton (as WeakReference of course) class, etc before starting Activity B, and pass just URI as parameter in Bundle.

Also check out this posts:
[Intent.putExtras size limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384619/intent-putextras-size-limit) and 
[Maximum length of Intent putExtra method? (Force close)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496700/maximum-length-of-intent-putextra-method-force-close)