# retrieve bytearray data from a file android

Tags: java, android

I am building an application in which I want to send bytearray from one activity to another. In order to do so I have saved the data in the file in byte form 'data1.txt'. At the time of retrieval the app slows down and stops working.
This is the code

```
public void read(String file) {
    String ret = "";
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(file);
        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                ret=ret.concat(receiveString);
            }

            theByteArray = ret.getBytes();
            inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File not found: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Can not read file: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it textual data you wrote to this file (did you write it using a `Writer`) or is it binary data (written using an `OutputStream`)?

Comment: When it stops working you must have a stack trace. Could you copy it here?

Comment: If it is textual data, change `ret` to be a `StringBuilder` and `append` each line to it.

Comment: public void save(String file, byte[] data){
        try {
           FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(file,MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
          fOut.write(data);
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"writin done",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           fOut.close();
        }

Comment: I have used fileOutputStrem to save data

Answer (score 1):

instead of sharing the byte[] over a file you could send it via an Intent:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {};
Intent i = new Intent("name.of.action");
i.putExtra("identifier", byteArray);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I have to send multiple data in form of byterarray. The data is too large for the intent

Comment: yes I have. It works fine for one file but I have to send data of four bytearrays. Can you suggest any another method??

Comment: Another possibility is to share it over a Singleton or the Application instance (which can easily become code smell if not done right) Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9385437/2355195